# Genymotion emulator need to move to other machine

Tags: genymotion

I am using Genymotion/VirtualBox on my PC and have retrieved, deployed and  successfully run a Genymotion virtual device on that PC.  Now I would like to move that same virtual device to another PC where I have installed Genymotion/VirtualBox but not deployed any virtual devices.

I would like to know if it is possible to do this, and if so, what specific set of folders or files need to be copied to the second PC in order to launch my original virtual device on the second PC.

Comment: Please reopen question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Genymotion directory locate the device folder and copy it.
Once yo install Genymotion on the second computer locate the "Deployed" folder and paste folder from previous step.

Comment: This doesn't work. Genymotion does not register VMs based on their existence in the deployed directory.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?